# Simple optimization problem 2

Tags: optimization

[image]

Approaching this question, I first calculated the TOTAL cost of the trip (that is, $D(v) + F(v))$. This gave me $\dfrac{1}{v} (5v^{\frac 5 2} + 2059V + 150 000)$.

Am I right in saying I now have to calculate this cost in cents per km? And would I do this by dividing the cost (in cents per trip) by $v$?

Comment: What you have computed (and I think it should be
$\frac{2\nu^{\frac{5}{2}} + 2059\nu + 150000}{\nu} $
) is the cost *per trip*.  Since what you are asked is most economical speed for the trip and the cost for the trip, you just need to minimize the expression that you have computed.

Comment: @Malcolm ah! Thank you!